# rgdslam linking error

Tags: slam, navigation, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to build rgbdslam under ubuntu 11.10 and ros electric.
I'm following these [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam/evaluation) (point 2).

However it fails with the following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_ros_service_ui.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g2o::MatrixStructure::~MatrixStructure()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'g2o::MatrixStructure::~MatrixStructure()' is defined in DSO /home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/g2o/lib//libg2o_core.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/g2o/lib//libg2o_core.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/rgbdslam] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/rgbdslam/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12646/rgdslam-linking-error/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
something changed in ubuntu 11.10 s.t. new library-dependencies are required. I am currently updating the [our google code subversion repository](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/). I haven' tested it thoroughly, but feel free to give it a try.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-01-17**:
@Felix Endres Now it compiles and works...thanks!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-01-17**:
Forgot to check in the service definition. Sorry. Please try again

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-01-16**:
rgbdslam/rgbdslam_ros_ui.h: No such file or directory

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-01-16**:
@Felix Endres Thank. However it still fails: Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o
In file included from /home/serl-3d/Software/ros-stacks/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/main.cpp:24:0: ~/Software/ros-stacks/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/ros_service_ui.h:24:38: fatal error: